# At what level is the order of the alphabet(s) stored in software/operating systems?

Tags: string, character-encoding, alphabetical

Ordering something alphabetically isn't something we spend too much time worrying about. We learned the alphabet at a young age and now we know that it (Latin) starts with A, then B, then C etc. through to Z.

But where exactly is this order stored in a computer system?
High-level programming languages have all sorts of native functions for ordering collections alphabetically, but I assume they in turn rely on a lower-level reference to implement this?

In addition to the basic ordering, there must also be a way of storing the fact that `E, e, È,` and `Ê` all feature between `D` and `F`.

I am reasonably familiar with ASCII, Unicode, etc. but the extended character sets are not strictly ordered alphabetically so I assume the 'order' is stored elsewhere.

I am also familiar with the concept of Collation in databases, but again, I assume this relies on some lower-level implementaion?

**In short:**

*If I wanted to change the order of the 'alphabet', what would I change?*

*Where is this order (that we all intuitively know) ultimately stored?*

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of functions that sort alphabetic data: naive nonlocalized functions that expect all text to be ASCII and effectively sort by the ASCII code order, ignoring other characters or treating them in some odd way, and localized functions that apply locale-specific collating order. This is generally not an operating system issue, though e.g. sorting of file names in a system needs to be based on *some* collating order.

In the modern world, computer software should apply Common Locale Data Repository ([CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/)) as the basis for sorting, possibly enhanced by locale-specific rules. The CLDR model is based on layers or “deltas”: there is an overall default order, and a pan-European order that modifies it, and locale-specific orders that modify it. For example, in German ordering, “Ä” is treated as primarily equivalent to “A”; in many other languages, like Finnish, Swedish, and Estonian, it is treated as a separate letter placed after “Z”.